# Deleting multiple Rows in GridView using Checkbox, Delete button outside of the Grid, without going to database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, datatable

How do I delete multiple Rows in a `GridView` using a Checkbox, Delete button outside of the Grid, without going to database?

My purpose is to be able to delete multiple rows by SelectedCheckbox in the `Gridview`. After that, I use data show in gridview to make changes in database.

```
Dim dt As DataTable = ViewState("gridview")
Dim row As GridViewRow
For Each row In gridview.Rows
    Dim SelectedRow As CheckBox = CType(row.FindControl("cbSelect"), CheckBox)
    If SelectedRow.Checked Then 

        'gridview.rows(row.index).visible = false is not my case because those indexes are still there

    End If
Next
```

I couldn't use`gridview.rows(row.index).remove()`/`delete()`

My 2nd option is store gridview to datatable by viewstate(). When i try to remove index in the FOR EACH loop, it showed error because after the 1st remove the datatable reindex.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my 2nd option done by deleting row from bottom up.
I really appreciate If anyone could help me with my 1st option.

```
Dim dt As DataTable = ViewState("gridview")
    For i As Integer = gridview.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        Dim row As GridViewRow = gridview.Rows(i)
        Dim SelectedRow As CheckBox = CType(row.FindControl("cbSelect"), CheckBox)
        If SelectedRow.Checked Then
            dt.Rows(i).Delete()
        End If

    Next
    gridview.DataSource = dt
    gridview.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, yes, delete each row from the bottom up.  I believe it will be like this.

```
Private Sub Button_Delete_Checked_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button_Delete_Checked.Click
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If row.Cells("ToDelete").Value Then
            MessageBox.Show(row.Cells("SomeText").Value & " will be deleted.")

        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

As for the Insert Into, this methodology should work fine.

```
Dim Con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Music_Sales_Database.mdb;")
Dim Com As OleDbCommand
Dim SaleCode As Integer
Dim MusicID As String
Dim SubTotalPrice As Decimal
Dim Copies1 As Integer
Dim STR1 As String

SaleCode = 1

Com = New OleDbCommand
Com.Connection = Con
Connection.open()
For x As Integer = 0 To SalesDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
    MusicID = SalesDataGridView.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value
    SubTotalPrice = SalesDataGridView.Rows(x).Cells(5).Value
    Copies1 = SalesDataGridView.Rows(x).Cells(3).Value
    STR1 = "INSERT INTO Sales(Sales_ID, Sales_Date, Copies, Music_ID, Staff_ID, Total_Price) VALUES (@Sales_ID, @Sales_Date, @Copies, @Music_ID, @Staff_ID, @Total_Price)"
    Dim Comm As New OleDbCommand(STR1, Con)
    Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sales_ID", SaleCode)
    Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sales_Date", txtDateAndTime)
    Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Copies", Copies1)
    Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Music_ID", MusicID)
    Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Staff_ID", txtStaff_ID)
    Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_Price", SubTotalPrice)
    Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Comm.Dispose()
Next
Connection.Close()
```

Obviously, you need to modify this to suit your specific needs.